# Is it possible to identify which inner instruction is responsible for an error without relying on logs?

Tags: jsonrpc-api

It is feasible using logs, using some code similar that the one found in the explorer to create log indentation. But this falls apart when log truncation kicks in. This is also not great as for advanced error analysis this has to be paired with inner instructions data, if the stack height is present.

The Solana JSON RPC getTransaction call has stack height for each innerTransaction after the minor release 1.14

An example transaction where ix #4 failed in the inner instruction call to Symmetry engine
https://explorer.solana.com/tx/37yaeMSdhhZYs7bzdUfXHKL4xs6SKpk8SPWhZw7t9pDZNtPZ64ZM8c5yTs4bcfne4RBdbdJgacdH3UoeF4Wgns8E

The error itself is insufficient

```
    "err": {
        "InstructionError": [
            6,
            {
                "Custom": 6001
            }
        ]
    },
```

The inner instructions end with the call to Symmetry engine + the token transfers, it looks like there is no way to deduce it failed in the symmetry engine not in the last token transfer. The ambiguity involves the last listed program and all the caller programs in the stack.

Is it then impossible and almost a bug?

Comment: There's no way to be totally sure unfortunately, so you could call this a bug.

Since a transaction bails at the first failure inner instruction failure, you can roughly assume that if a transaction failed, it happened in the last inner instruction. But this doesn't cover the case where a program CPIs into a program, which succeeds, and then returns an error afterwards because some post-condition wasn't met.

Answer (score 1):

For the tx you provided as a sample, you can see the where the error occurred in the logs:

```
  > Program log: AnchorError thrown in programs/funds/src/lib.rs:659. Error Code: ExceedsTargetWeight. Error Number: 6023. Error Message: Token weight after swap exceeds target weight.
  > Program Symmetry Engine  consumed 158683 of 1160139 compute units
  > Program returned error: custom program error: 0x1787
```

It helps when the developer adds a `msg!()` or event before the error occurs, which in this case it seems they have helpfully done as well:

```
  > Program log: TXINFO:Start:SwapFundTokens:J3sLNA54CYcVJURGVmMNi5xAaoJLn7HF6dA4WuAP8XXR
  > Program log: TXINFO:FundFee:4:0
  > Program log: TXINFO:FundTVLIncrease:4:76427
  > Program log: TXINFO:SymmetrySwapFee:4:0
  > Program log: TXINFO:HostSwapFee:4:0
  > Program log: TXINFO:ManagerSwapFee:4:0
  > Program log: TXINFO:Swap:5:2301206093:4:50083962
  > Program log: TXINFO:End
  > Program log: TXFAILINFO:ToTokenWeight:Token:4:Before:7:After:92:Allowed:175
```

But in general, it is annoying when the logs truncate!